Redundant whole house surge protector on subpanel
I have read that you can have redundant surge protectors (one on a main panel, another on a sub panel), but I'm not sure it's worth the cost (~$100). An HVAC contractor thought I needed one on the workshop sub panel to protect the delicate minisplit electronics even though I have one on the main panel.
I will have relatively powerful equipment on the sub panel (220V table saw, jointer/planer) if that is a factor for protecting from equipment-generated surges.
If so, I just install it further upstream immediately next to the shut off on the sub panel, just like the main panel, right?

If it's truly "redundant" you don't need it. More "additional" or "supplementary" than "redundant" as described. Where is the workshop sub-panel with respect to the main panel that has one already?

The sub-panel workshop is on a separate structure about 75 feet away, and the cable connection is in-ground in conduit. Both panels are installed on exterior walls.

Then (separate structure, outside cable run) you definitely want a surge protector there, IMHO.

You install a whole panel surge protector the same way in a subpanel as you do in the main panel. I spot checked a few sets of instructions just to make sure I wasn't forgetting anything, and yep, the instructions for subpanels are the same.
